Android Studio doesn't show the full attribute names
When I open the Attributes windows in Design layout of an XML file, the attribute names aren't shown completely unless I expand the Attributes window to half the screen.

When I do expand, it shows

I have tried looking in settings but I haven't seen anything relevant to the problem. I used the invalidate and restart option.
